# DotNet CLI Tool fails with "No executable found matching command "dotnet-migrate-2017"

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, command-line-interface, csproj

I am trying to use migrate-2017 to migrate some csproj files to the new more concise vs2017 project format.  I installed the tool from https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017 using the command:

```
dotnet tool install --global Project2015To2017.Migrate2017.Tool
```

When I try to use it I get this:

```
C:\projects\Trilogy\Main>dotnet migrate-2017 wizard
No executable found matching command "dotnet-migrate-2017"
```

However, it appears to exist....

```
C:\projects\Trilogy\Main>dotnet tool list -g
Package Id                              Version      Commands
------------------------------------------------------------------------
project2015to2017.migrate2017.tool      4.0.0        dotnet-migrate-2017
```

The global.json looks fine....

```
C:\projects\Trilogy\Main>type global.json
{
   "sdk": {
     "version": "2.1.602"
   }
}
```

And so does the version:

```
C:\projects\Trilogy\Main>dotnet --version
2.1.602
```

I'm using dotnet CLI tools for the first time, so what obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: As an aside:  do you need a global.json file?  Generally they are not recommended.

Comment: Have you opened a bug on it? I think I had the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything, but here's a few things to try:

- Does running `dotnet-migrate-2017` work (no dotnet required first)?
- Does the tool exist under `%userprofile%\.dotnet\tools`?
- Have you tried restarting the command prompt to force refresh your `%PATH%`?
- Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package?

Comment: I tried all these things.  I believe the problem related to my PATH.  After I restarted my computer all worked well.

Comment: Indeed I was having this issue, and after reading your comment, just closing my command prompt and reopening was good enough.  It was the same prompt from which I installed the tool.

Comment: Thanks @user1169420 I added that suggestion as well.